# disable basic auth on static content using spring security

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I have an angular app being served as a static content from a spring boot app. The angular app is inside target/classes/static/index.html of spring boot app. I also have a rest api served from spring boot and it needs to have basic auth enabled. I have configured my security config as below

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecrityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("john123").password("password").roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
}}
```

The basic auth is working as expected for the rest endpoint. But when I try to load the angular app from localhost:8080/springbootappname/ it's prompting credentials. When I give the credentials that I have configured, the angular app is being loaded.

So, I need help disabling this basic auth for angular app that is being unpacked into classes/static/

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it couple of way to server static contents.

1. You can override Security for static content.

   ```
   @Override
     public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
       web
         .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/target/classes/static/**");
     }
   ```
2. You can even manage it in http security override with matching antmacher.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/target/classes/static/**").permitAll()
           .anyRequest().authenticated()
           .and().httpBasic()
           .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
   }
   ```
3. Better to manage your static content from resources.please see link

https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot

Comment: hey I tried with the above configuration, it didn't work. Basically /target/classes/static/** isn't a path right?  spring boot will generate a jar and when I extract that jar angular app will be present in BOOT-INF/classes/static/index.html along with other static resources. I need to disable basic auth for the static resources here.

Comment: Yes, put here actual path /target/classes/static/ you have your static contents.

Comment: Which option you tried and is it still asking to enter user/pass or any other error.

Comment: i tried both, none of them worked. It's still asking for username and password